# How can I work on a pre-existing raspberry pi/sd card on my computer without re-writing over the card?

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, setup

I was given a raspberry pi 3 B vol. 2 that uses sonic pi to control a walk-on piano and am trying to work on the code contained on the micro sd card, but when I try to open it for the first time through the raspberry pi imager it gives a message that it will re-wrtie over the existing information. Is there a way that I can view and edit the contents on this card even though I was not the one to initially set it up and do not have access to the computer/person who did?

Comment: open it using a file explorer on the Raspberry Pi

Comment: You can access the partition on any Linux computer (including the Pi).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the RPi root ext4 file system by inserting SD card into a different computer?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9515/how-to-access-the-rpi-root-ext4-file-system-by-inserting-sd-card-into-a-differen)

Answer (score 0):

The SD Card contains partitions that are formatted with a filesystem. You can mount these partitions to an existing directory structure so you can access them. You need another computer with an SD Card slot or a USB SD Card adapter so you can attach the SD Card to the computer. You should use a Linux operating system on the computer like Debian or Ubuntu or any other. If not available you can use a Live CD. You can also flash a new image with a Raspberry Pi OS to a second SD Card and boot it with your RasPi. Then attach the first SD Card with an USB adapter to it.

Then you can mount the partitions on the SD Card to a directory on the computer, for example:

```
debian ~$ sudo mount /dev/sdx2 /mnt
debian ~$ sudo mount /dev/sdx1 /mnt/boot
```

This will give you access to the partitions on a default Raspberry Pi OS image. The root partition with programs and data is accessible on `/mnt/` and the boot partition with firmware and kernel you will find in `/mnt/boot/`.

I cannot give a tutorial here about mounting filesystems. Please have a look at the web for an appropriate tutorial.